# Saving multiple hadoop datasets concurrently in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery

I have a Spark app that looks like this:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MyApp")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val rdd1 = ...
rdd1.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(output1)

val rdd2 = ...
rdd2.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(output2)

val rdd3 = ...
rdd3.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(output3)
```

```

The call to `saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset` and while some of my workers are doing IO, it would be nice if the job continued to run the next stages.

I tried to wrap each computation in a `Future {}` and await on all of them at the end but ran into this issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13631

Is there a way in Spark to save to Hadoop dataset in a way that will queue other stages? FWIW, Hadoop's output configuration is BigQuery connector (https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/bigquery-connector)

Comment: any solution you achieved for this?

Comment: nope, the question is still open.